# How to keep some package from obfuscating?

Tags: android, package, proguard

In my app I have some package under src/, like packagename/dtd, which I want to keep it from obfuscating. Then what should I write in proguard.cfg to make it?

Sorry, pretty new to proguard. Thanks all for any hint. Kindest regards, Nessus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .pro file, try adding this:

```
-keep class packagename.dtd.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```

[Source](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#library)